# Unable to change function keys like before

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, imac

In the past versions of Mac OS X, I used to be able to change the function keys behavior. 
[image: This is the option that no longer exists]

But now that option is no longer. Does anyone know how to do it now? (Yosemite 10.10.5)
Using a Razer Anansi keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a separate keyboard?

Comment: As that section shows different info depending on what keyboard you connect [see @sdayal 's post with the keyboard brightness & turn off, which mine doesn't have] , presumably your Razer isn't correctly telling the Mac about its configuration. New drivers might be the answer - Razers seem to have this type of issue frequently.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's there under Keyboard Settings (assuming using are using mac keyboard):

[image]